# How to do Async/Await in the nativescript?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

For example if I have a simple app with a welcome-page.js and welcome-view-model.js I would start with something like this form the welcome-page.js

```
 const app = require("tns-core-modules/application");
 const WelcomeViewModel = require("./welcome-view-model");
 const welcomeViewModel = new WelcomeViewModel();

 let page;

 exports.onNavigatingTo = (args) => {

    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = welcomeViewModel;

    welcomeViewModel.doSomething().then((response) => {
      page.bindingContext = response
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
    })


 }
```

then on the welcome-view-model.js page i would have

```
  const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
  const ObservableArray = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

  function WelcomeViewModel() {

    const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
      dpiWidth: platformModule.screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs,
    dpiHeight: platformModule.screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs,
    isSubmitted:false,
    error:"",
    userDetails:"",
    allMonths: new ObservableArray([]),
    month1: new ObservableArray([])
  });

 viewModel.doSomething = (arg) => {
   return doSomethingThatReturnsAPromise();
 }

  return viewModel;
}

module.exports = WelcomeViewModel;
```

So how would I convert that to use async/await? I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=176&v=9F0sRJQYR9k&feature=emb_logo but it does not show how I do it using Javascript, only Typescript in this tutorial.

Comment: If your compiler target is ES6 then you could use the exact same code in JavaScript too. You will need TypeScript helpers only if your target is ES5.

Comment: I know the code works. I was  just hoping to improve it for my use case using async/await .

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I meant the async/await code you found for TypeScript can just work with JavaScript if the target is ES6, you wouldn't need any further changes.There is a good [blog post](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/use-async-await-with-typescript-in-nativescript-today) about using async/await in {N}, you will not need TypeScript helpers mentioned in the blog post with latest version of {N}. The helpers were required in older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just use async/await keywords and wrap them in a try/catch block if you think the promise can fail.

```
 exports.onNavigatingTo = async (args) => {

    ...

    try {
       const response = await welcomeViewModel.doSomething();
       page.bindingContext = response;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will give it a try.